# How to include a php file in 404.php file?

Tags: 404-error, include

I have created a log to track some attacks on a website. At the moment I have included it directly in the 404 file like this:

```
<?php get_header();

global $porto_settings;
require_once(ABSPATH.'log404.php' );
?>

HTML Code

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I know it's not the correct way but I've searched and I can't find how to include the log.php in the 404 file with a snippet. (I use the code snippet plugin)

Also, what would be the correct way to include it, in the header or in the footer? with the same snippet...

---

**[edited]**

I have verified that it is not good to add it the way I have done it because the 404 file does not print the HTML code, I have put it in the footer and it seems to work better.

```
<?php get_header();

global $porto_settings;
require_once(ABSPATH.'log404.php' );
?>

HTML Code

<?php 
require_once(ABSPATH.'log404.php' );

get_footer(); 
?>
```

**@jacob**: I have programmed log404.php and it records all the traffic that reaches that page (works great) and generates this:

```
01/04/2023 18:50:38 - 45.61.188.154 - United States - Miami - GET - /wp-login.php 
01/04/2023 19:03:58 - 198.98.62.37 - United States - Staten Island - GET - /wp-login.php 
01/04/2023 19:33:58 - 45.61.187.155 - United States - Miami - GET - /wp-login.php 
01/04/2023 19:56:25 - 45.61.187.155 - United States - Miami - GET - /wp-login.php
```

It is in the root of the site. I use the Porto Theme and for my codes I use the Code Snippets plugin, soon I will finish my plugin for this purpose.

**@popnoodles**: Before I had added it to the site index directly in the wp-config, like this:

```
// OCHOA LOG
require_once ABSPATH . 'log404.php';
```

But it registers things I don't want, customer visits, plugin usage, our work when modifying or adding products. And I think the same will happen if I add it to the wp_head (correct me if I'm wrong please).

```
01/04/2023 11:03:55 - 66.249.66.43 - United States -  - POST - /?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments
01/04/2023 11:04:00 - 95.217.195.123 - Finland - Helsinki - GET - /?add_to_wishlist=2113
01/04/2023 11:04:27 - 81.203.113.156 - Spain - León - GET - /lavadora-miele-w2819irlw-55kg-1400-rpm-integrable-a/?https://webSite.es&gclid=CjwKCAjwrJ-hBhB7EiwAuyBVXaRCE7cX9RG1I-Lv8bt5agBIFlNDFiNrq8Wtaox1e97Mq-3rRaF9CRoCZREQAvD_BwE
01/04/2023 11:04:29 - 37.135.26.57 - Spain - Ribarroja del Turia - GET - /?https://webSite.es&gclid=CjwKCAjwrJ-hBhB7EiwAuyBVXT4bjduEDZmFJavL7s12jM2cQnkoCeLq6u9tDcsiMbiGgHieEcVe6BoC2hsQAvD_BwE
01/04/2023 11:04:59 - 88.10.103.154 - Spain - Pamplona - POST - /?wc-ajax=get_refreshed_fragments
```

That's why I have it and I want it in the 404.php because it gives me only the IPs that are trying to reach the administration of the site.

PS: I have hidden all the administration (wp-admin, wp-login) and they have never been able to do anything, my purpose is to block the IPs that are generating this unnecessary traffic.

PS2: Sorry, my English is not very good yet.

Comment: What's in log404.php? Is it located in the theme or the root directory? Are you using your own theme or a child theme?

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I have edited the question and I have answered your comment there for a better understanding.